# How to simulate the predictor data with an available response and known regression parameters

Tags: generalized-linear-model, simulation

I would like to simulate some predictors to test the parameter estiamtes in different situations, but I have no idea how to do this. I have already had an available response data (Y). How to do this if we have already known the parameters and the intercept for the predictor which need to be simulated.

Suppose the target model is the generalized linear model with a log link function as below.

$ln(P_{Y = 1|Exposure}) = 1.2 \times Exposure + 0.8 + \epsilon$

My question is how to simulate the binary $Exposure$ given the model above and the available Y.

Much appreciated if provided with an example in a commonly used statistical software.

Comment: Since probabilities must be bounded between $0$ and $1$, you are better off using a [logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) link function. In your simulations, you need to choose the marginal probability of exposure (call it $\gamma$). Then in R, you can simulate using something like `exposure <- rbinom(n, 1, gamma); prob <- logit_inverse(1.2*exposure + 0.8); y <- rbinom(n, 1, prob)`. You will need to fill in some gaps in that code for it to run, but It contains the general ideas.

Comment: Hi @knrumsey, thanks for your answer. Your answer is fairly clear and it works when we have already known about the marginal distrbution of the exposure of interest. What if we only have the marginal distribution of the response variable P(Y = 1), is it possible to simulate an exposure variable that satisfy the equation as above so that I'm able to obtain both the conditional probablity of Y given the exposure and the marginal probability of the exposure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since probabilities must be bounded between $0$ and $1$, you are better of using a logit link function
$$\text{logit}\left(P(Y=1|\text{Exposure})\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\text{Exposure}.$$
To simulate data you need to select values for the coefficients $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ as well as the marginal probability of exposure $\gamma$. The following code will suffice in R

```
exposure <- rbinom(n, 1, gamma)
prob     <- logit_inverse(beta0 + beta1*exposure)
y        <- rbinom(n, 1, prob)
```

where `logit_inverse = function(x) 1/(1+exp(-x))`.

To address the question you posed in your comment, let's start by finding the expected value of $Y$. Let $X$ denote exposure.

\begin{align*}
E(Y) &= E(E(Y|X)) \\
&= E\left(\frac{1}{1+ \exp(-\beta_0 - \beta_1 X)}\right) \\
&= \gamma\cdot \frac{1}{1+ \exp(-\beta_0 - \beta_1 )}  + (1-\gamma) \frac{1}{1+ \exp(-\beta_0 )}
\end{align*}

Now if we plug in your values $\beta_0 = 0.8$ and $\beta_1 = 1.2$ we get
$$E(Y) \approx \gamma \cdot 0.8808 + (1-\gamma)\cdot 0.6899 = .6899 - 0.1908\gamma$$
Solving for $\gamma$ gives $\gamma = \frac{0.6899 - E(Y)}{0.1908}$. So this lets you choose $\gamma$ conditional on $E(Y)$, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!